# TestNG IMethodInterceptor intercepts a test class twice

Tags: testng

I have a simple test case

```
@Listeners(MyListener.class)
public class SampleTestCase {

@Test
public void testCase1() {
    Assert.assertTrue(true, "Let it pass all the time");
}
}
```

Where the Listener is

```
public class MyListener implements IMethodInterceptor {

static int count = 1;

@Override
public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
    System.out.println("Intercepted " + count++);
    return methods;
}
}
```

Output is :

Intercepted 1

Intercepted 2

PASSED: testCase1

Why is it intercepted twice?